# Laravel ::when on paginate, length undefined

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

I want to have a dynamic sizing of my pagination, I'm using laravel vue and inertiaJS, I receive the value but can't make it work on paginate inside when.

This is the query.

```
Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->when($request->search, function($query,$term){
                $query->where('code', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%');
            })->when($request->column, function($query, $term) use ($request){
                $query->orderBy($term, $request->order);
            })->when($request->size, function($query, $term){
                $query->paginate($term);
            }),
```

I get a length of undefined.

Comment: can you show full code of that controller method ?

Comment: 'groups' => Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->when($request->search, function($query,$term){
                $query->where('code', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%');
            })->when($request->column, function($query, $term) use ($request){
                $query->orderBy($term, $request->order);
            })->when($request->size, function($query, $term){
                $query->paginate($term);
            })

Comment: It looks like on mount in my VueJS, it doesnt send the form which has default values, how do I send a request on mount for this?

Comment: i dont know much about vuejs .$query->orderBy($term, $request->order); here orderby $term using and    $query->paginate($term);

Comment: even if I use `$query->paginate($request->size)`, `$query->paginate(5)`, and `$query->paginate($term)` all does not work when inside.

Comment: first of all try hardcoding value so you can verify which part is not working .thats the simple method.also check whether it reaches inside when call back

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $term = 10;
    $query = Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->when($request->search, function($query,$term){
        $query->where('code', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%');
    })->when($request->column, function($query, $term) use ($request){
        $query->orderBy($term, $request->order);
    });
    if(request()->size != null) {
       $term = (int)request()->size;
    }
    $query = $query->paginate($term);
```